# Swagger does not work on Docker in the Digital Ocean cloud

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, digital-ocean

In a locally launched application in .NET 5, **SWAGGER** works without any problems. (also on Docker installed in Windows 10)

In the **Digital Ocean** cloud (with automatic building and running of applications directly from the Github branch) **SWAGGER** does not work (even the `swagger.json` file cannot see)

The difference I can see is that **DigitalOcean** requires the **Dockerfile** to be in the root directory and running locally or Docker on Windows requires the **Dockerfile** in the directory where the .csproj file is located. Could it matter?

For Digital Ocean, I can't change it because it's automatic.

**Dockerfile:**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["doma_api/doma_api.csproj", "doma_api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "doma_api/doma_api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/doma_api"
RUN dotnet build "doma_api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "doma_api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "doma_api.dll"]
```

**Startup.cs: (Configuration)**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "DOMA API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "doma_api v1"));
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

What could be the reason **Swagger** doesn't run in the cloud?

Answer (score -2):

The problem was that the default **Swagger** configuration was placed in `IsDevelopment()`.

It should look like below. Now works fine

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "doma_api v1"));

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```